# Finding the score vector and Fisher information matrix for multivariate case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

In my review questions I have a question that indicates $X_{i}$ follows a $Bin(1,p_{i})$ distribution where $p_{i} = (1+e^{-\alpha - \beta q_{i}})^{-1}$ and the $q_{i}$'s are known constants. I am supposed to find the score vector and Fisher information matrix.

Now my problem is that although I understand the definitions of each of those, I am totally lost as to how I'm supposed to apply it to the multivariate case as I have here, as I've only seen one parameter cases. How should I approach this?